# Python: Problem Importing Function From Another Module

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import

I have a module called nbemail.py and in this module I want to use the function package_post defined in the module main.py. I am using this statement:

```
from api.main import package_post
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name package_post
```

I really don't know why I am getting this error! I do have _*init_*.py files in the api directory (which contains the files nbemail.py and main.py) and I do have the function package_post defined in main.py.

Any idea to help fixing this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the directory in which `api` lives is in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Well, my code lives in AppEngine, so I don't deal with PYTHONPATH. I am already importing other modules like api.blog, api.user, etc., and they all live under the api folder, so I assume there is no path problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you have a circular dependency error. Do you import `nbemail` from `main` as well? If so, Python won't be able to resolve the dependency. The best way to fix this is to move one of the imports into a function, so it doesn't happen when the module is first imported.

Comment: Oh, that's a good suggestion. Thanks man. I have this statement in main.py: from api import nbemail. Your suggestion is also good, but doesn't it look a bit messy and confusing? Others reading the code might get confused as to where that module is imported, and then they may probably think it isn't imported and import it again, only to come back to the same problem. Any other suggestions?!

Comment: @Rafid: well, the alternative is to move the `package_post` function into its own separate module, then you can import it from both `main` and `nbemail` without causing a circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If nbemail.py and main.py are in the same folder (as i understood in your question), just do this in nbemail.py :

from main import package_post

Comment: I tried this already, I got this error: ImportError: cannot import name package_post.

Comment: this seems to be related to GoogleAppEngine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437791/google-app-engine-importing-my-own-source-modules-multiple-files